# Rspec: How to use expect to receive with a resource which does not exist yet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In an action called via a post request I'm creating a resource call `RequestOffer` and send an email with `ActionMailer` using the created resource as a parameter:

```
@request_offer = RequestOffer.new(request_offer_params)
if @request_offer.save
    RequestOfferMailer.email_team(@request_offer).deliver_later
end
```

When my controller spec, I want to test that my `RequestOfferMailer` is called using the method `email_team` with the resource `@request_offer` as a parameter.

When I want to user `expect(XXX).to receive(YYY).with(ZZZ)`, the only way I found was to declare my expectation before making the POST request. However, `ZZZ` is created by this `POST` request, so I have no way to set my expectation before.

```
# Set expectation first
message_delivery = instance_double(ActionMailer::MessageDelivery)

# ZZZ used in .with() does not exist yet, so it won't work
expect(RequestOfferMailer).to receive(:email_team).with(ZZZ).and_return(message_delivery)
expect(message_delivery).to receive(:deliver_later)

# Make POST request that will create ZZZ
post :create, params
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is a functional test then I would isolate the controller test from the DB.  You can do this by using `instance_doubles` and let statements.  Here's an example that you may like to extend for your purposes

```
describe '/request_offers [POST]' do
  let(:request_offer) { instance_double(RequestOffer, save: true) }

  before do
    allow(RequestOffer).to receive(:new).
      with(...params...).
      and_return(request_offer)
  end

  it 'should instantiate a RequestOffer with the params' do
    expect(RequestOffer).to receive(:new).
      with(...params...).
      and_return(request_offer)
    post '/request_offers', {...}
  end

  it 'should email the request offer via RequestOfferMailer' do
    mailer = instance_double(ActionMailer::MessageDelivery)

    expect(RequestOfferMailer).to receive(:email_team).
      with(request_offer).and_return(mailer)

    post '/request_offers', {...}
  end
end
```

The key to this is using 'let' to declare an instance double of the model that you intend to create.  By setting expectations on the class you can inject your instance double into the test and isolate from the DB.  Note that the 'allow' call in the before block is there to serve the later specs that set expectations on the mailer object; the 'expect' call in the first test will still be able to make assertions about the call.

Comment: insead of using a test double you could also test the implementation of the RequestOfferMailer class by calling 

`expect(RequestOfferMailer).to receive(:email_team).and_call_original`

This way you also test if the mailer works correctly. You might as well do this in the mailer spec, but this way you check if the controller action works all the way

Answer (score 2):

The last argument of the `with` method is a block. You can open up the arguments and do anything you like there.

```
expect(RequestOfferMailer)
  .to receive(:email_team)
  .with(instance_of(RequestOffer)) do |request_offer|
    expect(request_offer.total).to eq(100) # As one example of what you can to in this block 
  end.and_return(message_delivery)
```

You can also set the `instance_of` matcher to be `anything` if you're not even sure what object type you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be enough to make sure the argument is an instance of `RequestOffer`? Then you could use the `instance_of` matcher. For example:

```
expect(RequestOfferMailer).to receive(:email_team).with(instance_of(RequestOffer)).and_return(message_delivery)
```

I found this option in the Rspec 3.0 docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments

Comment: I would ideally test more than that. However your link offer something that could be a solution, user a customer matcher: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments#using-a-custom-matcher I could define one checking that it's an instance of a RequestOffer by also that the important attributes are equal, like phone_number and email in my case that are required in the template of the email. Let's see if someone has a simpler solution, but thank you already for the hint!